# query with group by and count missing zero counts Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I can get the counts for column `E` (there are no empty cells in the range) with

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!D2:H,"select D, count(E) where F = 'person-person' group by D")
```

But if I add a second `where` clause

```
=QUERY(Sheet1!D2:H,"select D, count(E) where F = 'person-person' and H = 'Acquaintence' group by D")
```

I am missing the zero counts which I need

Thanks for any assistance with this

Google sheet w/data
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p0gM4fHWjPf9k40h_GrJjqj8KrxSJDQ-E10LAOgS--Y/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: share a copy (sample) of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: what do you mean by "the zero counts"?

Comment: I added a Google sheet with an example, sorry about confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({Sheet1!D2:D,N(Sheet1!F2:F&Sheet1!H2:H="person-personAcquaintence")},"select Col1,SUM(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1"))

SUM()'ing in a query lets you show 0s in a way that counting doesn't really.

Comment: Thank you Matt, this worked based on your approach `=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({connections!D2:D,N(connections!H2:H="Acquaintence"), connections!F2:F},"select Col1,SUM(Col2) where Col1<>'' and Col3 ='person-person' group by Col1"))`

Comment: Matt can you explain this part? `,N(connections!H2:H="Acquaintence")` thanks

Comment: @xyz333 glad i got you in the vicinity! connections!H2:H="acquaintence" just generates an array of TRUE/FALSE's. N() turns TRUE/FALSE values into 1s and 0s, so summing 1s and 0s acts like counting.

Comment: That's a good trix, I will remember it! Thanks again